# How to collect data results in pytest using junitxml?

Tags: python, xml, pytest

Let's use the following code (conftest.py) :

```
import random
def test_val():
    value = random.random()
    assert value < 0.5
```

Running `py.test --junitxml=result.xml conftest.py` generates `result.xml` (when the test passes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="" skips="0" tests="1" time="0.047">
<testcase classname="conftest" name="test_val" time="0.0"/>
</testsuite>
```

Now. What I'd like to be able to do is to store the value generated by `test_val()` in `results.xml`. Is there a way to do it ? I can't seem to find anything related in [pytest doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html).

Comment: May be the old problem of unit testing; tests are supposed to pass or fail -- nothing else :-/  And only in case of failure a message is considered.

Comment: Well, in the first case, if the test fails, you will get the actual result in the py.test output. Another option is to use jenkins to run py.test and get some reports (how many pass/fail...), at the end, the goal is either pass or fail, and the interest is only when you fail.

Comment: Thx @Juan I've simply added another "test" that gathers all the test results and stores them in a separate [JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shipped junitxml plugin does not have hooks to add such data
you can print it to stdout though, since that gets added to the junitxml data.

So as long as you print out logs you will at least be able to know the data.

Answer (score 6):

Years have passed and the best solution should be noted.

From the Pytest's [record_property](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#record-property) fixture docs:

> Add extra properties to the calling test.
>
> User properties become part of the test report and are available to
> the configured reporters, like JUnit XML.
>
> The fixture is callable with name, value. The value is automatically
> XML-encoded.

Properties are captured for both passed and failed cases.

Suite:

```py
def test_passes(record_property):
    record_property("key", "value1")
    assert 1 == 1


def test_fails(record_property):
    record_property("key", "value2")
    assert 1 == 2
```

Result when ran `pytest` with `--junitxml=result.xml`

Generated Junit test report:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="pytest" errors="0" failures="1" skipped="0" tests="2" time="0.085"
               timestamp="2021-04-12T14:25:09.900867" hostname="DESKTOP">
        <testcase classname="test_something" name="test_passes" time="0.001">
            <properties>
                <property name="key" value="value1"/>
            </properties>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="test_something" name="test_fails" time="0.001">
            <properties>
                <property name="key" value="value2"/>
            </properties>
            <failure message="assert 1 == 2">record_property = &lt;function record_property.&lt;locals&gt;.append_property
                at 0x000001A1A9EB40D0&gt;

                def test_fails(record_property):
                record_property("key", "value2")
                &gt; assert 1 == 2
                E assert 1 == 2

                test_something.py:8: AssertionError
            </failure>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

If the version of Pytest you run is quite new, you'll see deprecation warning

```
test_something.py::test_fails
  test_something.py:6: PytestWarning: record_property is incompatible with junit_family 'xunit2' (use 'legacy' or 'xunit1')
    def test_fails(record_property):
```

This is due to the fact that schema of Xunit reports had changed. From Pytest [changelog](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/pkgsrc/devel/py-test/Makefile):

> - record_property now emits a PytestWarning when used with junit_family=xunit2: the fixture generates   property tags as children
>   of testcase, which is not permitted according to the most   recent
>   schema <https://github.com/jenkinsci/xunit-plugin/blob/master/

To overcome warnings you can:

1. Run Pytest with override flag `-o junit_family="xunit1"` or place this property on `pytest.ini`
2. Use [record_testsuite_property](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#record-testsuite-property) session-scoped fixture. Nevertheless this allows only to attach properties to test suite level.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve your problem but not with junitxml.

You can use [`pytest-harvest`](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-harvest/) for this. Simply install it, and you can directly use the pre-defined fixtures:

```
import random

def test_val(results_bag):
    value = random.random()

    # save it (before test !)
    results_bag.value = value

    assert value < 0.5

def test_synthesis(module_results_df):
    """
    Shows that the `module_results_df` fixture already contains what you need
    """
    # drop the 'pytest_obj' column
    module_results_df.drop('pytest_obj', axis=1, inplace=True)

    print("\n   `module_results_df` dataframe:\n")
    print(module_results_df)
```

Yields

```
>>> pytest -s -v

============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 2 items
tmp.py::test_val PASSED
tmp.py::test_synthesis 
   `module_results_df` dataframe:

          status  duration_ms     value
test_id                                
test_val  passed     0.999928  0.443547
PASSED

========================== 2 passed in 1.08 seconds ===========================
```

You could then decide to dump the dataframe as a csv or any other format in a dedicated file. Note that you do not have to write the above in a test, you can do it from any of the pytest hooks (either where you have access to the above fixtures, or to a pytest `request.session` object).

See documentation for details.

Finally, if you wish to also use parameters, fixtures, steps... you might wish to look at this [datascience benchmark example](https://smarie.github.io/pytest-patterns/examples/data_science_benchmark/)

I'm the author by the way ;)